# Why isn't clientID enough for using Google APIs?

Tags: javascript, youtube, single-page-application, google-signin

From [Google's API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/youtube/m/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=statistics&id=UCE5Au4LfcBHxTQR_yLbncrQ&_h=4&) and using **Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0** as I want to on my SPA, I see a **YOUR_API_KEY** is somehow derived from a login and used in subsequent calls to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCE5Au4LfcBHxTQR_yLbncrQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

How do I get this key? I am working from [GAPI.auth2.getAuthInstance()](https://github.com/kaihendry/vue-aws/blob/master/src/services/auth.js#L23) in a VueJS app.

I can see **gapi** being used in [Google samples](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests). But I just want to do simple direct `fetch` calls with this user's API key for the session. I do not want to use `gapi.client`, or do I have no choice?

Update: On the [Oauth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) I see it refers to a client secret [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db9Oq.png). I don't understand this at all, since with a SPA with no backend, you don't want to store a secret! Why isn't the client ID and the **origin** enough?

[image: Client secret in Oauth token request]

Here's [another confusing example](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html#L69) (no secret used) where the **apiKey** is used together with the **clientId**. Why isn't **clientId** enough, since it's restricted by origin?!

Comment: If I understand your question properly, are you trying to get your API KEY, it should be in your Google Developer's Console? That will be your API Key, if you have a random an API Key and you are trying to Fetch() data, it will won't work because this API key will not match the Auth credentials.

Comment: I expect the API key to be clearly derived somehow from the GAPI.auth2 object. I.e. once user has authenticated/authorised with a Google login. There shouldn't be an API key from the API console for my App IIUC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, there are 2 types of OAuth flows to obtain an access_token when on the web. One is called [implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) and other is called [authorization code flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1).

For the code flow, you would require the client_secret in order to exchange a code with an access_token. This usually happens on server side.
For the implicit flow, you can simply give a client_id to obtain an access_token and it is designed to work on client side.

The screenshot you've attached is the OAuth flow part where you exchange an auth code with an access_token. Because the playground is using the authorization code flow.

What you are looking for should be the implicit flow.

To achieve this in YouTube client library (or whatever Google javascript client lib), you don't need a client_secret. You can find a complete example using Google Drive here:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/google-sign-in/blob/master/static/scripts/authorization_client.js

Comment: Thank you! But how do I just get **access token**, since I am not a fan of the `gapi.client` style APIs? I also filed a bug upon https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/344

Comment: You can get a raw access_token using `AuthResponse`.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authresponse
But the best way is to use the client library.

Comment: One more question: what is `id_token` needed for?

Comment: It's a proof of an authentication. You can validate it with the identity provider. Also you can obtain the user's profile information out of it.